# Regex to find brackets and text

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to do a find replace in visual studio and I cant seem to find how to find `[Name]`using regular expressions...I can find the first bracket with help from other questions on stack but it wont find both the beginning and the end AND recognize the text inside the brackets.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using?

Comment: If `[Name]` is a fixed bit of text, why use regular expressions at all? Just search for the text.

Comment: because i need to replace the entire thing `[Name]` not just `Name` and regular find and replace does not find  brackets

Comment: Really? If you turn off regular expressions then it will find any characters that you type in the box, regardless of what they are.

Comment: ummmmmm actually no it won't...at leastit didn't for me HENCE me asking this question!!!!!

Comment: I don't know what settings you are using, but if you untick all the Find Options then it *most definitely will* find any literal text. I have just tried it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to **escape** the opening and closing brackets, as they are regex metacharacters. Something like this:

```
\[Name\]
```

Answer (score 2):

Brackets are usually operators of the regexp engine

```
[a-z]    # everything from 'a' to 'z'
[^a]     # everything except 'a'
[^a]+    # one or more chars excluding 'a'
```

So if you want to match the actual bracket characters you need to escape them (with antislash) so in this case your regexp will start with `\[` and end with `\]`

What do we put in between? We need to be able to have anything except the closing bracket, repeated one or more times. That would be :

```
 [^\]]+   # one or more chars excluding ']'
```

So all in all your answer is:

```
 \[[^\]]+\]
```

Comment: ah i didn't understand that your 'Name' was a given value! the answer by newStackExchangeInstance and C. H. address this case. Mine is useful when we need to match any _unknown_ expression between brackets

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "name" is any valid identifier, then `\[{:i}\]` should do the trick. You can use `\1` in your replacement expression to get the value of the name.

NOTE: `:i` is a Visual Studio only shortcut. The standard regex equivalent (which also works here) would be `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`.

NOTE: To any readers not familiar with Visual Studio regexes, curly brackets are used to capture groups instead of the normal round brackets used everywhere else.

Comment: your answer was very comprehensive but newStack's answer was first and also worked...